# Error on looping String array of public static final String[]

Tags: android

hi I'm doing a project/app that listing image from a certain site uri,
there is too much uri to be type on so i made a for loop for the data to loop:

I wan to make this

```
public final class c{

public static final String[] IMG = new String[]{
    "http://mywebsite.com/image1.png"
    "http://mywebsite.com/image2.png"
    "http://mywebsite.com/image3.png"
    ....(many more)
    };
}
```

into this but error occur

```
public final class c{

public static final String[] IMG = new String[80]; //**<-- got an error Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token**

    for(int x=0;x<80;x++){
      **IMG cannot be resolved to a variable--->**IMG[x]="http://mywebsite.com/image"+(x+1)+".png"
    }
}
```

do i need to add a public static void?

thx~

Comment: Executable code, like a for loop, must be in a method or a static initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a mistake. You can not use a for() loop here. Do it like this:

```
public final class C{
    public static final String[] IMG = new String[80]; //**<-- got an error Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token**

    private void setUp() {
        for(int x=0;x<80;x++){
            IMG[x]="http://mywebsite.com/image"+(x+1)+".png";
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can new C().setUp() to initialize IMG.
if C extends Activity,setUp() when onCreate().
There is a better way:

```
public final class C{
    public static final String[] IMG = new String[80]; 

    public static void setUp() {
        for(int x=0;x<80;x++){
            IMG[x]="http://mywebsite.com/image"+(x+1)+".png";
        }
    }
}
```

Before you use IMG,call **C.setUp()**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're declaring a final array, it expects you to tell it exactly what it is. Get rid of final.